# Android: How can I perform a click on a ListAdapter or SimpleCursorAdapter?

Tags: android

So I cant figure out how to perform an onClick on my ListAdapter. Here is my code:

```
private void fillData(){
    Cursor constantsCursor = db.fetchAllGames();

    ListAdapter adapter =
        new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, 
                constantsCursor, new String[] { "title", "console" }, new int[] {
                R.id.title, R.id.console });
    setListAdapter(adapter);


}
```

I want to be able to click on an item from the database, then go into a view that only contains info for that item. My class currently extends ListActivity. I've tried OnItemClickListener, but I dont know what else to use to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your current `Activity` extends `ListActivity` then you need to override [`ListActivity#onListItemClick`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#onListItemClick%28android.widget.ListView,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long%29) to get the clicked view from the `ListView`.